# Getting error as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to post data via ajax but getting error below is my code

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url : '',                           
                    type: 'POST',                                           
                    data : {oid:1934,ConsigneeAddress1:85/18 BDD
CHAWL,ConsigneeAddress2:D N WAKARIKAR
MARG,ConsigneeMobile:097731454620,ConsigneeName:V
Boga,ConsigneePincode:400018,CommodityDetail1:SOVA Draksh & Bitter
Orange
..,CreditReferenceNo:1934,InvoiceNo:1934,PickupDate:2018-03-29,SubProductCode:C},
                    success: function(data)
                    {               
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hint. This is not valid js  `ConsigneeAddress1:85/18 BDD CHAWL`

Comment: The code producing the `data` property is obviously riddled with syntax errors, of course it doesn't run. The solution is to fix the syntax errors. The first one is as of the `B` in `ConsigneeAddress1:85/18 BDD`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-in-future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following and please wrap your string values in quotes. Read - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    oid: "1934",
    ConsigneeAddress1: "85/18 BDD CHAWL",
    ConsigneeAddress2: "D N WAKARIKAR MARG",
    ConsigneeMobile: "097731454620",
    ConsigneeName: "V Boga",
    ConsigneePincode: "400018",
    CommodityDetail1: "SOVA Draksh & Bitter Orange..",
    CreditReferenceNo: "1934",
    InvoiceNo: "1934",
    PickupDate: "2018-03-29",
    SubProductCode: "C"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```